# Insomnia: invalid csrf token

Tags: insomnia

Even after providing all valid credential and token refresh "insomnia" keep throwing "invalid csrf token" token in response.

I tried refreshing token, restart and changing different credentials nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Insomnia stores old token information in cookie. To get rid of this problem delete cookie.

Here is how to delete cookie:

Cookies can be added, viewed, modified or deleted within the cookie manager, accessible button at the top of the sidebar.